# "Reset filter" button missing in admin panel completely

Tags: products, category-products, related-products

I have used "Reset Filter" button before in various screens, now i tried to add related products and I am not able to add it as I couldn't find the "Reset Filter" button and also no way to search for the products in the screen. It happens to category page as well to add new products to category. Not sure what happened.

Running 1.9.2 (Stable)

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you added any extension which rewrite class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid ?

Comment: if this is global issue with reset button check for rewrite / overwrite

Comment: @MineshPatel yes its a global issue.. what should I check for? not sure what do you mean by rewrite/overwrite.. I am pretty new here..

Comment: all grid file extends class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid if any module is rewriting this class then it might cause issue so check that

Comment: Thanks a lot.. That helped me find the issue. For some reason i had changed $this->setFilterVisibility(false); to this inside Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All grid file extends class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid if any
>   module is rewriting this class then it might cause issue so check that
>   first.